# Done button toolbar on iPhone 12 mini and 13 mini simulator not showing on loading time picker. Is this a bug?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, simulator

I am working on iOS app in Xamarin with VS 2019. When I run the app on iPhone 12 mini and iPhone 13 mini simulators then toolbar added in timepicker is not showing, but the same code is working fine with all other simulators. Is there any kind of bug in iPhone 12 mini and iPhone 13 mini?  [here is screenshot in iPhone mini 12 & 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LDkQ.png) and [this is in other iPhones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIU6D.png) and this is my code:

```
            NSDateFormatter timeFormat = new NSDateFormatter
            {
                TimeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Short,
                DateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.None
            };
            timeFormat.DateFormat = "hh:mm a";
            UIDatePicker picker = new UIDatePicker
            {
                Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
            };

            var date = currenDate;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUITextField.Text) && objUITextField.Text != "--:--")
            {
                date = Convert.ToDateTime(objUITextField.Text);
            }
            NSCalendar calendar = NSCalendar.CurrentCalendar;
            var components = calendar.Components(NSCalendarUnit.Hour | NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: NSDate.Now);
            components.Hour = date.Hour;
            components.Minute = date.Minute;
            picker.SetDate(calendar.DateFromComponents(components), animated: true);

            //For 12 Hrs 
            picker.Locale = new NSLocale(identifier: "en_US");

            //for ios version >= 14
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
            {
                picker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;
            }

            // Setup the toolbar
            UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar
            {
                BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default,
                Translucent = true
            };
            toolbar.SizeToFit();

            // Create a 'done' button for the toolbar and add it to the toolbar
            UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Done", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                                             (s, e) =>
                                                             {
                                                                 objUITextField.Text = timeFormat.ToString(picker.Date);
                                                                 objUITextField.EndEditing(true);
                                                             });
            UIBarButtonItem cancelButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Cancel", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                                           (s, e) =>
                                                           {
                                                               objUITextField.EndEditing(true);
                                                           });

            var flexibleSpace = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: null, action: null)
            {
                Width = MainWidth - 50
            };

            if (objUITextField.AccessibilityValue == "endtime")
            {
                UIBarButtonItem clearButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Clear", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                                             (s, e) =>
                                                             {
                                                                 //code
                                                             });
                toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { doneButton, flexibleSpace, clearButton, cancelButton }, true);
            }
            else
            {
                toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { doneButton, flexibleSpace, cancelButton }, true);
            }

            //Display the toolbar over the pickers
            objUITextField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
            objUITextField.InputView = picker;
            picker.SizeToFit(); //Add this in ios14
            picker.SetNeedsDisplay();
```

Comment: "Is there any kind of bug in iPhone 12 mini and iPhone 13 mini?" Yes, these simulators are well known to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test on iOS 15 ?

It works without problem on my side ,please check the following screen shot.

I used your code , the only modification is that I hard code the `Width` value of `flexibleSpace`  , because you did not provide `MainWidth`  .

Comment: MainWidth is just a variable with UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width value. The toolbar is initially hidden but when I click on Cancel button space, it hides the time picker. It sometimes show sometimes not.

Comment: I am testing this on 14.5 and 15.0. It sometimes show toolbar sometimes not.

Comment: Consider raising the issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues.